# C# Moq SetUp Linq Function

Tags: c#, linq, moq

I'm going back over someone's code and adding some Unit Tests. I was hoping someone could help me create a Moq setup for Linq?

My query is something like

```
var someitem = _someRepo.GetAll().Where(x=> x.CustomerId == customerId)
                                 .OrderByDescending(x=> x.DateAdded)
                                 .Take(3)
                                 .ToList();
```

I'm not sure how to set up multiple conditions (.Where(), .Take() etc...)

Would I have to set up each of them separately or it their a better way?

Comment: You should be mocking `_someRepo` `GetAll` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better method would be to have the query and conditions in a method on the repository itself. Then, you can mock that method and not worry about it at all.

For example (I'm making some guesses on entity names etc):

Repository class

```
public List<Customer> GetLatestThreeCustomers()
{
    return Where(x=> x.CustomerId == customerId)
                             .OrderByDescending(x=> x.DateAdded)
                             .Take(3)
                             .ToList();
}
```

Note, you probably don't need the `GetAll` method, if you're using Entity Framework `Where` will still get the correct results without it.

Then, just mock the `GetLatestThreeCustomers` method in your test class.

If you can't make a new repository method, you could just mock `GetAll` by itself, which would then let you test the order and query as you can control what it returns (so you could return nothing, nothing that matches, different dates etc).

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the prompt method. Your suggestion is what I would normally do. However, we are moving towards a generic repo model (this repo hasn't been moved over yet) so I'm avoiding creating specific methods.

Comment: @S-Unit see my edit, you could just do `GetAll` in that case as a stop-gap until your new model is ready.

Comment: Thats great thanks. I guess I was trying to make it more complex than it needed to be.